# Why is using ng-model twice for input fiel working?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a form with an input field that requires two values for ng-model. One to set the input field to required, the other to store the value that is typed into the input field. I just tried around and I know that it's not possible to assign two different values to ng-model. I also tried using ng-model two times and it's working. I am wondering why? That would not be legitimate, right?
Here is my code snippet:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl"> 
<form name="myForm" novalidate>        
    <label>First Name</label><br>
      <input class="myClass" type="myCtrl.mapType" name="req" ng-required="isReq" ng-blur="isReq=true" ng-model="myCtrl.details.firstname.value" ng-model="required">
        <div ng-show="myForm.req.$error.required" class="error">Field is required! 
    <label>Last Name</label><br>
      <input class="myClass" type="myCtrl.mapType" name="req" ng-required="isReq" ng-blur="isReq=true" ng-model="myCtrl.details.lastname.value" ng-model="required">
        <div ng-show="myForm.req.$error.required" class="error">Field is required!</div>
    <button class ="button" ng-click="myCtrl.save()">Save</button>          
</form>
</div>
```

Can anyone explain? If I do not provide the first name in the input field and click into the second input field, the error message is displayed correctly. And once I save the form, the given data is also saved correctly despite the two ng-models.

Comment: I dont think you need ng-model for required ... you can just use ng-required   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired

Comment: Can you explain what you expect the ng-model="required" to do? It seems to me as it's not what you expect. Also I think it might be working because you will have two model controllers (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel), they might end up conflicting but it could seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it binds value with very first ng-model. There might be something you are missing.

```
<input class="myClass" type="myCtrl.mapType" name="req" ng-required="isReq" ng-blur="isReq=true"  ng-model="myCtrl.details.lastname.value" ng-model="required"><br>

first ngModel: {{myCtrl.details.lastname.value}}<br>
second ngModel: {{required}}
```

Comment: But how does one cleanly combine two models so to say? Do I need a directive for that?